# ¿Cómo listar y filtrar archivos recursivos en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un método recursivo para listar solo directorios con PHP y no encuentro en error que tengo.

```
function listarDirectoriosLocales($path,$level) {
    $path = rtrim(strval($path), '/');
    $d = dir($path);
    if (!$d)
        return false;
    $level ++;
    while (false !== ($current = $d->read())) {
        if ($current === '.' || $current === '..')
            continue;

        $file = $current;
        if (is_dir($file)) {

            echo "<div class='".$level."'id='dirnav'> ".$current."</div>";
            listarDirectoriosLocales($file,$level);
        }
    }

    $d->close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, como más datos aportes sobre el error o datos que quieres que devuelva, mejor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para listar solo los directorios y guardar su ruta en un array:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

function listarDirectoriosLocales($dir, &$results = array()){
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            //Es un Archivo
            //$results[] = $path;
        } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            //Es un directorio
            listarDirectoriosLocales($path, $results);
            $results[] = $path;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

echo '<h2>Listar Directorios Locales </h2><pre>';
print_r(listarDirectoriosLocales('/xampp/htdocs/test/'));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ya está resuelto.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez esto les pueda servir, el codigo genera una listado en formato json, de directorio donde se encuentra el archivo. sin má les dejo el codigo, que tome como referencia de www.desarrolloweb.com con una modificacion para ver no solo directorio si no los archivos adicionandolos a un arreglo de manera recursiva.introducir el código aquí

```
<?php
$data;
function listar_directorios_ruta($ruta){ 
     $data=array();
    // abrir un directorio y listarlo recursivo 
   if (is_dir($ruta)) { 
      if ($dh = opendir($ruta)) {
          $count=0;
         while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) { 
            if (is_dir($ruta . $file) && $file!="." && $file!=".."){ 
               //solo si el archivo es un directorio, distinto que "." y ".." 
              //echo "<br>Directorio: $ruta$file";
               $data['ruta']["$ruta$file"]=listar_directorios_ruta($ruta.$file . "/"); 
            }elseif($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                $data[$count]=$file;
            }
             $count++;
         } 
      closedir($dh); 
      } 
   }
    return $data;
}
$data=listar_directorios_ruta("./",$count,$data);
echo json_encode($data);
```